# ViMbAdmin and config nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a problem with the configuration of nginx. Structure directory in my server is:

- /var/www/public_html is my page.
- /var/www/pma - phpmyadmin
- /var/www/vimbadmin - ViMbAdmin

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server{
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    access_log  /var/www/log/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/log/error.log;
    root /var/www/public_html;
    index index.php index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location /pma/ {
        index index.php;
            alias /var/www/phpmyadmin/;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;

            }

    }
    location /vma/ {
            index index.php;
            alias /var/www/vimbadmin/public/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            index index.php;
            location ~\.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    #try_files $uri =404;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }

    }
  }
```

Now when I go: domian.com/vma/ redirect me to domian.com/vma/auth/login and I see:

> File not found.

Phpmyadmin works.
I know that the configuration is bad... But where is mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

```
location ~ ^/vma {
    alias /usr/local/vimbadmin/public;

    location ~ ^/vma/(.*\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png|ico))$ {
        alias /usr/local/vimbadmin/public/$1;
    }

    rewrite ^/vma(.*)$ /vma/index.php last;

    location ~ ^/vma(.+\.php)$ {
        alias /usr/local/vimbadmin/public$1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        charset utf8;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /usr/local/vimbadmin/public;
    }
}
```

it works, at least on my machine ;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of ir1keren did not work for me with ViMbAdmin V3.0.11.

Here is how I did it:

```
#
# ViMbAdmin 3.0.x Nginx configuration

# Directory where ViMbAdmin is installed
set $vimbadmin /var/www/vimbadmin;

location /vma {
    alias $vimbadmin/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/vma/(.*\.(js|css|gif|jpg|png|ico))$ {
    alias $vimbadmin/public/$1;
    }

    rewrite ^/vma(.*)$ /mail/index.php last;

    # Pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {

        #try_files $uri =404;

        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/vma/(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV production;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass php-backend;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
   }
}
```